# Array operation of numbers

Tags: java

I want to write a program for this operation,

I/p: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15

O/P: 1,3,6,10,15

This was asked me in the interview , I did it like this,

```
     class Num
     {
          public static void main(String args[])
          {
             int j=0,k=0,count=1;
             int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
             for(int i=0;i<=(((a.length+2)/2)-k);i++)
             {
                 k++;
                 count++;
                 System.out.println(a[j]);
                 j+=count;
             }
          }
     }
```

It works but it looks little messy So is there any systematic manner to do this . and any tricks for doing this kind of operation.

Comment: Maybe we should send this to Code Review? Since the OP already stated the code works, and only wants the code reviewed, Code Review seems the best place to host this question.

Comment: That's a massively oversimplified request. They haven't told you whether they want you to figure out what the formula is for selecting these values, or how they're going to be provided to you (string? array?, other?), or indeed whether you're supposed to select the relevant ones at all or just output the literal result they asked for. As it stands, it's impossible to code review, because we don't know what we're reviewing it against. We can guess, but we shouldn't have to... and if that's all they told you, they're going to mark you down for not asking for clarification.

Comment: Belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? Less messy.

```
 class Num
 {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         int input[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
         int step = 1;
         for(int i=0;i<input.length;i+=step)
         {
             System.out.println(input[i]);
             step++;
         }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way.

```
class Num
 {
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    int sum = 1, count = 0;
    System.out.println(sum);
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = count == 1 ? i : ++i) {
        int bitmask = arr[i]<<1;
        if (count==0) {
            System.out.println(sum+=bitmask); count++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(sum+=bitmask+1); count--;
        }
    }
 }
```